# Assumptions behind Synthetic Control Methods

Tags: regression, inference, causality, synthetic-controls

I am trying to estimate the impact of a minimum wage policy in a given region and I was initially thinking of only using a DiD design. However, I came across this causal inference [post](https://causalinf.substack.com/p/the-much-quieter-revolution-of-synthetic) on synthetic control methods SCM, and I am now considering but was curious if one method is "superior" to the other. Specifically, I want to know if I should pick my own control group based on institutional knowledge, as in the case of a DiD.
Or use SCM to create an artificial control group based on a dataset of all 8 regions in X country I am studying.

I have several macro variables/indicators at the region-level on both my treated and control regions, and both before and after treatment. These variables include:

```
unemployment rate
Labor fore participation rate
employment rate 
Gini coefficient
share of prime-age workers
median household income
median individual income
poverty rate
% of population on food stamps
% of workforce receiving unemployment insurance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantages over DID:

- It relaxes the parallel trends assumption.
- It can work with fewer treated units, often just one
- Easier to explain compared to a table of regression coefficients.

You can select your *potential* donor group using institutional knowelede, and then let SC algorithm reweight those selected units. This is recommended in the SC literatuire. Personally I would pre-register the set of potential donors and then check "all regions" version for robustness.

Comment: dimitriy, do you have a good recommendation for understanding the SC weighting algorithm? I think Abadie does too much abbreviation in the technical sections from the 2003, 2007, and 2021 articles on synthetic controls, and I would love to be able to learn it with enough depth to program the weights-estimations algorithm myself.

Comment: Those are all the same papers I've read. I would take a look at Synth: An R package for synthetic control methods in comparative case studies
A Abadie, A Diamond, J Hainmueller - Journal of Statistical Software, 2011 and the code (or another implementation).